# How to protect init function of a C based library?

Tags: c, synchronization

I have written a C based library and for it to work in multi-thread parallely, I create some global mutexes in the init function.

I expect the init function to be called in the main thread before the library APIs are used in multi-thread.

But, if the init function itself is called in multi-thread directly, then it is a problem. Is there a way to protect the init function itself from my library? One way I can think of is to ask the application to create a mutex and protect parallel calls to my init function, but can I protect it from my library itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use teh default entry point functions.

In windows you can use `DllMain` to create and destroy your mutexes.

On Linux and probably some other Unixes you can use `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` on your entry and exit functions.

In both these case, the functions will be called once on load and unload

Comment: Can these be used only with dlopen or will this work even if we link the dynamic library using -l option to the application?

Comment: This seems to be GCC Specific option. I have an application in which the library will be linked using -l option and the same library will be loaded using dlopen also. What will happen in that case? Will the constructor be called twice?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Constructor and Destructor work for standard executables as well. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes

Answer (score 2):

POSIX has the `pthread_once` function

```
int pthread_once(pthread_once_t *once_control,
              void (*init_routine)(void));
```

In the linux man page they then have the following instructive example

```
static pthread_once_t random_is_initialized = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
extern int initialize_random();

int random_function()
{
 (void) pthread_once(&random_is_initialized, initialize_random);
              ... /* Operations performed after initialization. */
}
```