# pthreads: how to assert code is run in a single threaded context

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, fork

I am writing a C library which needs to fork() during initialization. Therefore, I want to assert() that the application code (which is outside of my control) calls my library initialization code from a single threaded context (to avoid the well known "[threads and fork don't mix](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them)" problem). Once my library has been initialized, it is thread safe (and expected that the application level code may create threads). I am only concerned with supporting pthreads.

It seems impossible to count the number of threads in the current process space using pthreads. Indeed, even googletest only implements [GetThreadCount()](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/src/gtest-port.cc#128) on Mac OS and QNX.

Given that I can't count the threads, is it somehow possible that I can instead assert a single threaded context?

Clarification: If possible, I would like to avoid using "/proc" (non-portable), an additional library dependency (like libproc) and LD_PRELOAD-style pthread_create wrappers.

Clarification #2: In my case using multiple processes is necessary as the workers in my library are relatively heavy weight (using webkit) and might crash. However, I want the original process to survive worker crashes.

Comment: I know its not portable, but its a start: On Linux, there is [/proc/self/stat](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: How about "if (pthread_self() != NULL) ..."?
Sorry, that's not useful if you want to check that there aren't OTHER threads than the first one, of course. Sorry. Will keep thinking...

Comment: On further investigation, I'm not sure there is any easy way to solve this problem. Perhaps just "document it clearly and let the user suffer if they are not reading docs?"

Comment: ArjunShankar, for the portability reason that you mention I would like to avoid using "/proc" if possible. I edited the question to clarify. Mats Petersson, that is a creative idea. As you state, ideally I would like to assert that no OTHER threads exist as well.

Comment: Why are you forking, and what will you do after the fork?  It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem without understanding why it's a problem.  Depending on the specifics of what you are doing, the problems with forking and threads may not be a problem at all, or there may be other problems you're ignoring that are unrelated to threads.

Comment: evil otto, in my forked process I am using libc functions which could get deadlocked waiting on internal libc locks (eg: malloc, stdio functions, etc). Also it is possible that my library is linked with a custom allocator (eg: tcmalloc) which performs internal locking. If the fork() does not occur prior to threads being created in the original process it is very difficult to write code that (safely) does more than calling execve.

Comment: nos, True -- I didn't justify the reason for using a separate process. However, lots of valid possible reasons exist and (especially for the case of a library) ensuring a single-threaded environment seems like something that is generally useful. In my case the forked process is relatively heavy weight (using webkit w/ IPC) and I want the original process to be able to survive in the event the forked process (or one of it's workers) crashes.

Comment: The point is well taken though nos and evil otto. I could launch my other processes via another mechanism than fork() -- that just might make setting up/using the library a bit more burdensome on the end-user. Still, I think the functionality (of checking for a single-threaded execution context) is generally useful.

Comment: It seems like you considered a ksh-like coprocess model, can you implement what you want in a detached process - a daemon?  -- that is how some solaris system software handles the situation I think you  describe.

Comment: jim mcnamara, thanks for the suggestion. I'll very likely do something along the lines of a daemon. Still, I'm interested if anyone has a creative solution for this problem at a pthreads level.

Comment: I would think that you don't really have any good solutions to avoid problems with mutexes and other synchronization tools... However, if the process you first created crashes, you're dead in the water anyway! I think the deamon solution as pointed out by Jim is the sensible solution in your case. Some more info, maybe pthread_atfork() can help you?
http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Alexis Wilke, yes, but it is possible for the first created process (during the library initialization code) to in turn launch other worker processes where the actual work is done. So long as the launcher process stays running, it can restart crashed workers to make the process crash not be terminal from the application code perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mark your library initialization function to be run prior to the application `main()`. For example, using GCC,

```
static void my_lib_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));

static void my_lib_init(void)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Another option is to use [`posix_spawn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn) to fork and execute the worker processes as separate, slave binaries.

EDITED TO ADD:

It seems to me that if you wish to determine if the process has already created (actual, kernel-based) threads, you will have to rely on OS-specific code.

In the Linux case, the determination is simple, and safe to run on other OSes too. If it cannot determine the number of threads used by the current process, the function will return -1:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

int count_threads_linux(void)
{
    DIR           *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    int            count = 0;

    dir = opendir("/proc/self/task/");
    if (!dir)
        return -1;

    while (1) {

        errno = 0;
        ent = readdir(dir);
        if (!ent)
            break;

        if (ent->d_name[0] != '.')
            count++;
    }

    if (errno) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        closedir(dir);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return -1;
    }

    if (closedir(dir))
        return -1;

    return count;
}
```

There are certain cases (like chroot without `/proc/`) when that check will fail even in Linux, so the `-1` return value should always be treated as *unknown* rather than *error* (although `errno` will indicate the actual reason for the failure).

Looking at the FreeBSD man pages, I wonder if the corresponding information is available at all.

Finally:

Rather than try detecting the problematic case, I seriously recommend you `fork()` and `exec()` (or `posix_spawn()`) the slave processes, using only async-signal-safe functions (see [`man 7 signal`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)) in the child process (prior to `exec()`), thus avoiding the fork()-thread complications. You can still create any shared memory segments, socket pairs, et cetera before forking(). The only drawback I can see is that you have to use separate binaries for the slave workers. Which, given your description of them, does not sound like a drawback to me.

Comment: the init/constructor trick is not going to prevent the problem of @ahochhaus if the library is loaded with `dlopen()`

Comment: @ydroneaud: I thought that saying "run prior to main()" would make that obvious. It's not like the code can go back in time..

Comment: Reading "/proc" isn't ideal, but I agree that the only way to count threads is OS specific so this type of solution is close to the best we can get. Thanks @Nominal Animal.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a SIGINFO signal to the process' controlling tty, the process should describe the status of threads.  From the description it should be possible to deduce whether any threads have been created.

You may have to develop a small utility that is invoked via popen to read the output back into your library.

Added sample code Fri Dec 21 14:45

Run a simple program that creates five threads.  Threads basically sleep.  Before the program exits, send a SIGINFO signal to get the status of the threads.

```
openbsd> cat a.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

#define THREADS 5

void foo(void);

int
main()
{    
    pthread_t thr[THREADS];
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < THREADS; j++) {
        pthread_create(&thr[j], NULL, (void *)foo, NULL);
    }   

    sleep(200);                             

    return(0);
}             

void
foo()
{   
    sleep(100);
}             
openbsd> gcc a.c -pthread
openbsd> a.out &
[1] 1234
openbsd> kill -SIGINFO 1234
 0x8bb0e000 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000          
 0x8bb0e800 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000          
 0x8bb0e400 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000          
 0x7cd3d800 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000          
 0x7cd3d400 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000          
 0x7cd3d000 sleep_wait  15 -c---W---f 0000 main
```

Comment: do you have any reference about this ?

Comment: 'man pthreads' on my system (OpenBSD) has it.  It is supposed to be POSIX 1003.1c thread interface compliant.

Comment: The man page doesn't have one. I have added a simple example to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Arun. This solution is the best answer to the original question (using only pthreads how to ensure ensure single threaded execution context) so I'm marking it as the answer. In practice, I think I am going to end up launching my worker binaries in another way (per some of the other comments).

Comment: @ArunTaylor this is a interesting feature, sadly not POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/signal.h.html has no definition for SIGINFO (which is not the same thing as SA_SIGINFO)

Comment: @ydroneaud, thanks for pointing out this isn't actually POSIX. I therefore removed the answer flag. It is a very creative solution though.

Answer (score -1):

You could use use [`pthread_once()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_once.html) to ensure no other thread is doing the same thing: this way you don't have to care that multiple threads are calling your initialisation function, only one will be really executed.

Make your public initialisation function run a private initialisation through `pthread_once()`.

```
static pthread_once_t my_initialisation_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static void my_initialisation(void)
{
    /* do something */
}

int lib_initialisation(void)
{
    pthread_once(&my_initialisation_conce, my_initialisation);

    return 0;
}
```

Another example can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fusers_27.htm).

**Links**

- [How to protect init function of a C based library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555815/how-to-protect-init-function-of-a-c-based-library)
- [POSIX threads - do something only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580509/posix-threads-do-something-only-once)

Comment: ydroneaud, Thanks - this is an interesting idea. However, as best I can tell, this does not ensure that the application code did not already spawn a different thread (that will never enter my library code but still could cause mutex deadlock) before initializing the library.

Comment: @ahochhaus if you also want to protect from a user not calling the init function before other function, *just* call the init function in all other functions: `pthread_once(&my_initialisation_conce, my_initialisation);`

Comment: @ahochhaus and you can still use one atomic global variable set only when the initialisation is completly done

Comment: I apologize if I am missing your point. Say the user spawns thread t1 and t2. In thread t1, the user will never interact with my library code at all but they will utilize other libc functions. In thread t2, they initialize my library (where I use your pthread_once trick). In this case, deadlock of the forked child can occur, however (unless I'm missing something) the pthread_once() trick you mention will not be able to detect thread t1.

Comment: @ahochhaus it seems that I'm also missing something: why there would any deadlock between two different processes having threads: threads from one process are unaware of the thread in another process, even if the process are relatives ?

Comment: @ahochhaus after reading again your question, I think I understand the *problem* you're trying to solve which is different from the one I solved.

Comment: say thread t1 happens to be inside a call to malloc (and holding an internal lock) at the instance the fork occurs. In the new process space that internal malloc lock will be held but never released. Therefore the first time I call malloc from the new process I will deadlock. See the "threads and fork don't mix" article linked in the initial question for more complete background. Did I not understand something about your solution that mitigates this case?

Comment: The only sane use of `fork()` is when it's part of a "fork then exec" pair. To me it sounds like you're using `fork()` when you should be using `pthread_create()` (and you should be using signal handlers to ensure that one thread can crash safely without effecting other threads).